# SAS stdi output clarification

Tags: sas, statistics

I'm attempting to convert some old SAS macros into Python, and am a bit unclear by some of the terminology used in SAS. In the macro, the PROC statement is

```
proc reg data=model_file;
model &y = &x;
output out=&outfile r=resid stdi=resid_error;
```

I understand that **`r`** means the individual residual per data point, but was unclear what **`stdi`** meant. According to the SAS manual, stdi means "standard error of the individual predicted value", so there is one stdi for each row in the dataset. I searched around a bit and found this [lecture slide from the University of Wisconsin](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st572-larget/Spring2007/handouts03-1.pdf) which I believe explains how to calculate **`stdi`**:
[image]

However, two (EDIT: ONE) questions remain:

1. Is the method for calculating standard error of individual
       prediction in the lecture slide indeed correct? I've never seen this
       method before so I still have my doubts. I've looked up the SAS manual, but their definition for STDI is a bit confusing:[image]. Specifically, h(i) is defined as [image] but I don't know what the bar after [X'X] is supposed to mean.
2. The way the standard error of individual predictions is calculated
       here utilizes **`x`**. However, what happens if you have run a
       regression with multiple X columns? Does **stdi** assume only a
       single X column?

Answer: the answer is no. You can have multiple X columns and still a STDI value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a statistician and your question could have included a lot more detail,  but a quick Google search suggests that you're looking at a PROC REG. The main documentation for PROC REG is here:

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect015.htm

and there is a dedicated page for "Model Fit and Diagnostic Statistics" including the relevant formulae here:

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect039.htm

Maybe that will answer your question. Although these things don't interest me directly, I believe that SAS's documentation is pretty good at always describing the exact computations being done by each procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What other details do you think are helpful for me to include in my question to give more guidance to answerers?

Comment: In this case, it would have been helpful to show more of the SAS code that you're converting to Python. The explanation of the 'terminology used in SAS' is very likely to vary depending on which PROC you're looking at. It's also helpful to add something like 'where can I find the documentation?', or 'I've checked the documentation here <exact URL> but it doesn't answer my question', that kind of thing, so that we don't waste time doing obvious steps that you may already have tried.

Comment: I've pored through the documentation from SAS, but their definition of STDI is unclear- I've explained further where exactly I'm confused in the edits to my question.